# What is the difference between stdin and STDIN_FILENO?

Tags: c

What is the practical difference, if any, between `stdin` and `STDIN_FILENO` in C?

Comment: [An interesting discussion on the topic](http://www.rtems.com/ml/rtems-users/2011/march/msg00101.html). Perhaps you should also ask why `fileno(stdin)` differs from `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: @user7116 Your link is unfortunately dead.

Comment: This link works http://www.rtems.org/ml/rtems-users/2011/march/thrd1.html#00101

Comment: @pixelbeat your link is dead as well :( anyone have an informative read on the subject?

Comment: rtems keep breaking links. Here's new location http://www.rtems.org/rtems/maillistArchives/rtems-users/2011/march/thrd1.html#00101

Comment: @pixelbeat link dead..

Comment: Latest link appears to be: https://lists.rtems.org/pipermail/users/2011-March/023277.html

Comment: I am settling this matter once and for all: https://web.archive.org/web/20180127193256/https://lists.rtems.org/pipermail/users/2011-March/023277.html

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The interface.  Like everyone else has said, `stdin` is a `FILE *` as defined by the standard c library.  You can use some of the higher level interfaces like `fread`, `fwrite`, and `fprintf`.  On the other hand, `STDIN_FILENO` is just a file descriptor (almost certainly 0).  This uses a slight lower level interface through the likes of `read` and `write`.

Comment: None of the answers mention that `STDIN_FILENO` is a macro defined in `<unistd.h>`. At least for a POSIX compliant system, it's not just "almost certainly 0"; it's required to be defined as 0. Similarly, `STDOUT_FILENO` is 1 and `STDERR_FILENO` is 2.

Comment: The `<unistd.h>` header [...] and the two constants `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` are part of the POSIX standard [...]. This header contains function prototypes for many of the UNIX system services, such as the `read` and `write` functions that we call.
The constants `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO` are defined in `<unistd.h>` and specify the file descriptors for standard input and standard output. These values are `0` and `1`, respectively, as required by POSIX.1, but we’ll use the names for readability. -- Source: Advanced Programming in the Unix ® Environment - 2nd edition page 9

Answer (score 26):

`stdin` is a default FILE pointer used to get input from none other than standard in.

`STDIN_FILENO` is the default standard input file descriptor number which is `0`.  It is essentially a defined directive for general use.

Answer (score 13):

From **`/usr/include/stdio.h`**,

```
/* Standard streams.  */
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdin;          /* Standard input stream.  */
extern struct _IO_FILE *stdout;         /* Standard output stream.  */
extern struct _IO_FILE *stderr;         /* Standard error output stream.  */
/* C89/C99 say they're macros.  Make them happy.  */
#define stdin stdin
#define stdout stdout
#define stderr stderr
```

From **`/usr/include/unistd.h`**

```
/* Standard file descriptors.  */
#define STDIN_FILENO    0       /* Standard input.  */
#define STDOUT_FILENO   1       /* Standard output.  */
#define STDERR_FILENO   2       /* Standard error output.  */
```

Ex, `stdin` (**`_IO_FILE`** defined in `/usr/include/libio.h`) is a structure data. `STDIN_FILENO` is a macro constant, which points to a file descriptor used by kernel.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void
stdin_VS_STDIN_FILENO(void)
{
    printf("stdin->_flags = %hd\n", stdin->_flags);
    printf("STDIN_FILENO  : %d\n", STDIN_FILENO);
}

int
main(void)
{
    stdin_VS_STDIN_FILENO();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind explaining what that code snippet at the end is supposed to show?

Answer (score 2):

stdin : 1. A file pointer (* FILE)
        2. The file descriptor table holds its address when process is 
           created.
        3. present in /usr/include/stdio.h

STDIN_FILENO : 1. It is a macro
               2. Its nothing but an array index of a file descriptor table 
                   (default 0).
               3.present in /usr/include/unistd.h

**Could be more clear by following code.**

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<unistd.h> 
int main() 
{    
     printf("%d\t\t%p ----- ",STDIN_FILENO,stdin);

return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The STDIN_FILENO in the linux header #include "unistd.h" is just a macro for 0 which stands for the stdin for the pipe, when you are using Linux pipe.

Comment: You're right, however (nitpick) pipes have nothing to do with this. The standard input is not always a pipe, for example `./command < some_file` in bash will not create a pipe. You can check whether it's a pipe or not by getting the pipe size: `fcntl(STDIN_FILENO, F_GETPIPE_SZ)` returns `-1` in this case. The same call returns `65536` (or another positive integer, ymmv) when stdin is a pipe (`cat some_file | ./command`)