# When setting terminal attributes via tcsetattr(fd.....), can fd be either stdout or stdin?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, termios

I have been looking int the [man 3 tcgetattr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcgetattr) (as I want to change the terminal settings in a program) and found this.

```
int tcgetattr(int fd, struct termios *termios_p);

int tcsetattr(int fd, int optional_actions,
              const struct termios *termios_p);
```

## Question:

I would like to know what `fd` should mean? (it seems to be `stdin`, yet I do not understand why)?

## Background

My comprehension is that terminal is input and output together, as my understanding was that a `/dev/tty` or `/dev/pty` yields `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` together.

Comment: fd means file descriptor

Comment: @HoKy22 thanks, and both mentioned options for `fd` , namely `stdin` and `stdout` are file descriptors, hence it is not clear and I need to ask

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`fd` stands for file descriptor, which is a reference to an OS file object.  Because it is a reference, multiple different file descriptors may refer to the same file object.

`stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are `FILE *` objects -- actual pointers to stdio `FILE` datastructures.  You can get the file descriptor that refers to the underlying OS object with the `fileno` function.

So there's two levels of indirection going on here.  The `FILE *` could all refer to the same `FILE`, but they don't; there are 3 separate `FILE` objects for `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.  These `FILE` objects each contain a file descriptor, normally 0, 1 and 2 (I say normally -- the OS/lib sets them up this way and they'll only change if you explicitly change them in your program).  The 3 file descriptors will then normally all refer to the same underlying OS object, which is a single terminal object.

Since there's (generally) only one terminal, and all these file descriptors (usually) refer to it, it doesn't matter which fd (0, 1, or 2) you use as the first argument to `tcsetaddr`.

Note that it *is* possible for these `fd`s to refer to different objects -- if you start your program with redirections (`<` or `>` in the shell) then one or more of them will refer to some other file object and not the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

To simplify [Thomas Dickey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35881173/5977581) and [Chris Dodd's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35874581/5977581) answers, the typical code to select which descriptor is used to refer to the terminal is

```
int ttyfd;

/* Check standard error, output, and input, in that order. */
if (isatty(fileno(stderr)))
    ttyfd = fileno(stderr);
else
if (isatty(fileno(stdout)))
    ttyfd = fileno(stdout);
else
if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
    ttyfd = fileno(stdin);
else
    ttyfd = -1; /* No terminal; redirecting to/from files. */
```

If your application insists on having access to the controlling terminal (the terminal the user used to execute this process), if there is one, you can use the following `new_terminal_descriptor()` function. For simplicity, I'll embed it in an example program:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int new_terminal_descriptor(void)
{
    /* Technically, the size of this buffer should be
     *  MAX( L_ctermid + 1, sysconf(_SC_TTY_NAME_MAX) )
     * but 256 is a safe size in practice. */
    char buffer[256], *path;
    int  fd;

    if (isatty(fileno(stderr)))
        if (!ttyname_r(fileno(stderr), buffer, sizeof buffer)) {
            do {
                fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
            } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
            if (fd != -1)
                return fd;
        }

    if (isatty(fileno(stdout)))
        if (!ttyname_r(fileno(stdout), buffer, sizeof buffer)) {
            do {
                fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
            } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
            if (fd != -1)
                return fd;
        }

    if (isatty(fileno(stdin)))
        if (!ttyname_r(fileno(stdin), buffer, sizeof buffer)) {
            do {
                fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
            } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
            if (fd != -1)
                return fd;
        }

    buffer[0] = '\0';
    path = ctermid(buffer);
    if (path && *path) {
        do {
            fd = open(path, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
        } while (fd == -1 && errno == EINTR);
        if (fd != -1)
            return fd;
    }

    /* No terminal. */
    errno = ENOTTY;
    return -1;
}

static void wrstr(const int fd, const char *const msg)
{
    const char       *p = msg;
    const char *const q = msg + ((msg) ? strlen(msg) : 0);    
    while (p < q) {
        ssize_t n = write(fd, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > (ssize_t)0)
            p += n;
        else
        if (n != (ssize_t)-1)
            return;
        else
        if (errno != EINTR)
            return;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int ttyfd;

    ttyfd = new_terminal_descriptor();
    if (ttyfd == -1)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    /* Let's close the standard streams,
     * just to show we're not using them
     * for anything anymore. */
    fclose(stdin);
    fclose(stdout);
    fclose(stderr);

    /* Print a hello message directly to the terminal. */
    wrstr(ttyfd, "\033[1;32mHello!\033[0m\n");

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `wrstr()` function is just a helper function, that immediately writes the specified string to the specified file descriptor, without buffering. The string contains ANSI color codes, so that if successful, it will print a light green `Hello!` to the terminal, even if the standard streams were closed.

If you save the above as `example.c`, you can compile it using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example.c -o example
```

and run using

```
./example
```

Because the `new_terminal_descriptor()` uses `ctermid()` function to obtain the name (path) to the controlling terminal as a last resort -- this is not common, but I wanted to show here it is easy to do if you decide it is necessary --, it will print the hello message to the terminal even when all streams are redirected:

```
./example </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Finally, in case you are wondering, none of this is "special". I am not talking about the *console terminal*, which is the text-based console interface many Linux distributions provide as an alternative to the graphical environment, and the only local interface most Linux servers provide. All of the above uses just normal POSIX pseudoterminal interfaces, and will work just fine using e.g. `xterm` or any other normal terminal emulator (or Linux console), in all POSIXy systems -- Linux, Mac OS X, and the BSD variants.

Comment: enjoyed reading your informative answer and its code, thank you. The reason why `wrstr()` and its `write()` do not cause the system to buffer is something I do not understand. My take was that indeed that totally depends on the settings of that terminal device, i.e. setting `ICANON`  flag in `struct termios.c_lflag` should [make input "available line by line."](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html). What am I missing, which part of your good code did set this ?

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: You didn't miss anything, I just worded myself badly. I was referring to the buffering that for example standard C I/O does for `stdout` by default. In essence, `wrstr()` just hands off the string to the kernel immediately -- much like a `fputs(str, stdout); fflush(stdout);` would.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with @chris-dodd that the file descriptors corresponding to the streams *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* usually refer to the same terminal, some points are needed for the original question:

- the `fd` parameter (*file descriptor*) for [`tcgetattr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcgetattr.html) and [`tcsetattr`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetattr.html) has to be for a *terminal*.
- you could obtain this for a stream using [`fileno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fileno.html), e.g., `fileno(stdin)`.
- [POSIX defines constants](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/stdin.html) for the default assignment of file descriptors to *stdin*, *stdout* and *stderr* as `STDIN_FILENO`, `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO`.  However, it is possible to [reopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freopen.html) any of the streams (or use [`dup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) or [`dup2`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html)) and alter the actual file descriptor.
- while you can obtain a file descriptor for a stream, if you are doing anything interesting with the terminal attributes, that can interfere with the buffering used for streams.  If you have to mix the two (file descriptor and stream), do the changes to terminal attributes *before* reading or writing the stream.
- you can also get a file descriptor using an `open` on the terminal device.  This is useful if the streams are redirected, and your application has to work with the terminal.  Password prompts do this.
- the terminal device can be read from the program [`tty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tty.html) (even if *stdin*, etc., are redirected).
- programs can check a *file descriptor* using [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isatty.html) to see if it is a terminal.  If a stream is redirected to a file or pipe, it is not a terminal.

Further reading:

- [11. General Terminal Interface](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html) (POSIX)
- [What is the difference between stdin and STDIN_FILENO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102992/what-is-the-difference-between-stdin-and-stdin-fileno)

Answer (score 0):

By way of experiment I have found myself the following answer:

Each of the triple `stderr`,`stdout`,`stdin` was able to be used to change the terminal settings via the `tcsetattr(fd....)` function. Once a change was effectuated reading `tcgsetattr(stdin....)`,`tcgsetattr(stdout....)`, and also `tcgsetattr(sterr....)` returned the same content in the `struct termios.h` which could be verified via `memcmp(&termios_stdin,&termios_stdout,sizeof(struct termios)) == 0`

also maybe the man page stated somewhat indirectly this

> tcgetattr() gets the parameters associated with the object referred by
>   fd and stores them in the termios structure referenced by termios_p.
>   This function may be invoked from a background process; however, the
>   terminal attributes may be subsequently changed by a foreground
>   process.

about `fd` hence the object referred by fd is always the same terminal