# Detect whether macOS app was launched from the command line (Terminal)

Tags: macos, cmdline-args

I have a GUI macOS app that may also be launched from Terminal, with optional command line arguments.

When launched with arguments, I like to run the app in a "cmdline" mode where I do not display any UI but instead communicate via stdin + stdout only.

I can detect this cmdline mode like this:

```
BOOL cmdMode = NSProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.count > 1;
```

(arg 0 is always the executable's path, so any more args would be manually passed args).

Now, here's the big question:

If the user invokes my app *without* arguments from Terminal (by invoking the app's executable in *Contents/MacOS*, i.e. not via the `open` cmd), I like to also go into the cmdline mode. How do I detect this?

Note: Older OS X versions did pass a "-psn ..." argument that, when not present, could be used to detect a launch from cmdline, but recent macOS versions seem to not pass this argument any more when launching apps from the Finder, so I cannot use that for detection any more.

**Update**

I realize that I can almost correctly solve this by checking for the presence of certain environment variables:

`TERM` and `PWD` are only set when launching the app from Terminal but not from Finder.

However, I also like to be able to tell the difference between being launched directly (executable in Contents/MacOS dir) vs. launched with the `open` command as I consider the open cmd being equivalent to opening the app via Finder or from another app via Launch Services.

In short, the question might also be: **Detect whether an app was launched by Launch Services**

---

For the record, here are the values from `environ()`. The ones marked with an asterisk are only present when invoked from Terminal.app but not when lanched from Finder:

```
    __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x0
*   _=/Applications/Myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/Myapp
    Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.laVQnD7IXl/Render
    HOME=/Users/username
*   LANG=en_US.UTF-8
*   LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
*   LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
    LOGNAME=username
    PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
*   PWD=/Users/username
    SHELL=/bin/bash
*   SHLVL=1
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.KeHv8KNuuk/Listeners
*   TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=388.1.2
*   TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
*   TERM_SESSION_ID=EF2C59E6-D661-45BE-B7EF-7A0E71158C8D
*   TERM=xterm-color
    TMPDIR=/var/folders/hm/ycnxcbwx8xl1v7008k8wnpjh0000gn/T/
    USER=username
    XPC_FLAGS=0x0
    XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
```

There are, however, no envinment values that are unique to apps launched with Launch Services (such as when double clicked in Finder).

Comment: This question is absolutely on-topic here, so my comment does not represent a complaint or an argument to close the question, but it's worth pointing out that there's a potential pool of experts over on [apple.se] that may be able to help.

Comment: I don't think I'll get an answer on A D because that's for users, while I'm asking a programmer's question.

Comment: As noted I'm  not voting to close/migrate because your question is on-topic here, but looking at AskDifferent they seem to have MacOS/iOS specific programming questions as well. But there is a very good chance that those answering programming questions there will also participate here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know what process has executed your program, you could use `getppid()` to get the parent process ID, then inspect that process to determine whether you were executed by an interactive shell process, or Finder, or launchctl, etc.

`/sbin/launchd` is PID 1 - if your process's parent PID is 1, you were executed by launchd.

Otherwise, you were executed by another process - probably an interactive shell, or as a subprocess of another process. You can use the [`KERN_PROCARGS` syscall with `sysctl()`](https://gist.github.com/loderunner/1372bab8060b012b2117) to get the process name by its PID.

You might also want to consider using `isatty(fileno(stdin))` as well: interactive shells have a TTY, non-interactive shells and other processes won't.

Comment: I think the proper macro for the stdin fd is `STDIN_FILENO`

Comment: @mvds as `STDIN_FILENO` is a macro returning a constant value, the safest would be `fileno(stdin)` which returns the file descriptor of whatever the `stdin` stream is pointed to, in case it has been redirected.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102992/what-is-the-difference-between-stdin-and-stdin-fileno -- I will edit my answer to replace `isatty(STDIN)` to `isatty(fileno(stdin))` to correct it.